# using TCP or UDP

Tags: splunk

I can upload a file and analyse.

> splunk > Search > Add more data > from
>   files and directories

```
But how do I use TCP and / or UDP?
```

Assuming I have hosted splunk on 10.10.10.100, I want to access the logs on 10.10.10.99 and the location is "/var/log/somefile.log"
Currently I am copying the file from 99 to 100 and then analysing. Is there a better way to dynamically link to the source ?

Comment: You are going to have to clarify your question - right now this is too vague to answer with anything more than: "Using your favorite programming language, open a socket to the desired host and port".

Comment: You may be looking for a package like syslog-ng that allows log centralization or forwarding, see: http://blogs.splunk.com/2008/11/13/syslog-syslog-ng-and-splunk-forwarders/

Comment: If the latter is the case, I suggest migrating this over to superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options to accomplish this:

1. Install a Splunk forwarder on `10.10.10.99` and configure it to forward to `10.10.10.100`. This is the most reliable and flexible approach. See http://www.splunk.com/base/Documentation/latest/Deploy/Aboutforwardingandreceivingdata
2. Use syslog or syslog-ng to do forwarding from `.99` to `.100`. You can then set up Splunk to either monitor the syslog log file or listen directly on the syslog network port, depending on how you setup syslog. This is most efficient if you already have syslog running in your datacenter.
3. Setup a raw TCP (or UDP) forwarder on `.99`, i.e., [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat), and have it stream data over to `.100`.

In general, you will get a faster response to Splunk questions over at http://splunk-base.splunk.com/answers/.

Comment: Johnvey - I am using netcat to redirect my script logs to .100 (using the same example here). If I put the stream in a file and read it via splunk it works perfectly. But that means an overhead of saving the log twice. And If I directly listen on a port via splunk, there is no data log. Also, the data sources in the search module never show TCP/UDP as sources, only files. What seems to be the problem?